# Get a list of audit reviews for each review queue

Tags: support, data-explorer, review-audits

Is there a way (I suppose via Data Explorer request) to get a list of completed (with any result) audit review for each review queue on site?

Comment: See @rene's query [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306391/295232).